# Highlight Specific Dates in jQuery UI DatetimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Highlight date "2018-09-01","2018-09-10" and "2018-09-21" in jQuery UI DatetimePicker. "2018-09-01" highlight color is yellow. "2018-09-10" highlight color is red. "2018-09-21" highlight color is blue. I don't know I must create new function to highlight date or I can use even of datetimepicker.

```
$('#in').datetimepicker(
{
    format : 'Y-m-d',
    timepicker:false,
    onSelectDate : function(){
        dateCheck()},
    closeOnDateSelect:true
});
```

This is code for now. Thanks in advance for any help that you are able to provide.

Comment: I don't know of any built in functions. By inspecting the date picker, I believe you will be able to access the particular date using `data-year` and `data-month` attributes of the `<td>` and then look for `html()` of child `a` tag for date value.You will need to write a function to set style of multiple dates.

Comment: How can I use data-year and data-month attributes. `<td data-date="4" data-month="8" data-year="2018" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend"><div>4</div></td>`